# Where are the new Metas?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, meta

According to the most recent blog post, ServerFault and SuperUser each got their own Meta.

Shouldn't this be showing up in StackAuth?

Comment: They're there.  Ordering is not specified on StackAuth methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they are showing but at random spot.
http://stackauth.com/1.0/sites

They are just before GIS

Comment: Ah. Musta missed them somehow.